# SWFUpload with .net MVC require Windows login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, swfupload

i have a problem whith using SWFUpload in my MVC application. On some workstations uploader shows the Windows authentication dialog. I have no idea what it means. Project deployed on IIS 7. For some cliets it works for another no. Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Authorize attribute? Flash upload is not sending the auth cookie, so you have to hack a little
http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: removed all authorization from this action but no effect.